# Uploading Storing and Linking to Images on Google Container Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, kubernetes, flickr

I am developing an app where users can upload images. The app has a NodeJs Backend an Angular Frontend with a Redis and Neo4j all dockerize and run by  Kubernetes. Now I would like to store images, but there are so many service that I think could do the job that I don't know what to do... Can I use my Google Drive account and the Drive Sdk to upload the images of my users ? Should I look into Google Cloud Storage ? What about the persistence storage option in Kubernetes ? Or can I use my Flickr Account ??? Could someone point me the right direction... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For uploading and storing static files such as images in the cloud using GCP should probably be using [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/).

While both Google Drive and Google Cloud Storage provide an API to upload files, Cloud storage is more suited for your use case. I took this excerpt from [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/faq#services)

> Cloud Storage is intended to be accessed primarily through its API and
>   provides all the functionality necessary for developers to use it as a
>   backing store for their own applications.

and

> Cloud Storage enables developers to store their application data in
>   the Google cloud (and they’re responsible for the storage their app
>   consumes), whereas in Drive, users allow apps to interact with the
>   user’s private storage and content.